# Query on last modified time without a last modified column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle 10g XE. I have a database query -

```
SELECT PID FROM PROUCT WHERE last_modified > '${dih.last_index_time}'
```

What I'm trying to do here is compare the timestamps. The problem is that my table does not have a `last_modified` column neither I can add it to the table. However there is a query -

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP( ORA_ROWSCN ) FROM PRODUCT;
```

That will return a column that will contain the required timestamps.

How do I use this query in place of `last-modified` column to make the necessary comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply put it in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT PID 
  FROM PRODUCT 
 WHERE SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP( ORA_ROWSCN ) > '${dih.last_index_time}'
```

**However**, your two queries are not equivalent. From the [ORA_ROWSCN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953) documentation (my emphasis):

> For each row, ORA_ROWSCN returns the conservative upper bound system change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row in the current session. This pseudocolumn is useful for determining **approximately** when a row was last updated. **It is not absolutely precise**, because Oracle tracks SCNs by transaction committed for the block in which the row resides.

This means that if you modify one row in a block then the entire block (multiple rows) will have the same SCN.

If you want your query to be exact you need to either add in your LAST_MODIFIED column, or, potentially, enable [row-level dependency tracking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#CJAEEGDA). This would still not be exact:

> ... each row in the table has a system change number (SCN) that represents a time greater than or equal to the commit time of the last transaction that modified the row

Comment: The query didnt work. I got an error - "unable to execute query"

Comment: It works for me @Archit: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f047f/1. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Aaahh... sorry. My bad!
Im now getting the following error
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: ${dih.last_index_time} stores the date as follows - 2013-07-23 17\:23\:28 . Am i doing anything wrong?
Im quite new to all this. I would be very grateful to you if you could provide me with a solution. @Ben

Comment: Is that actually a date though @Archit? Or, are you passing it as a string? You need to either convert this to a datetime in whatever language you're using or use an explicit [`TO_DATE()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) in Oracle, i.e. `TO_DATE(<date string>,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` but only you can tell for sure...

Comment: Keep in mind that [SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions161.htm#BABEHBCB) only works for a "limited period of time".  Eventually you'll get the error `ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. What do you mean by "limited period of time"? @jonearles

Comment: Per the manual, the period of time is: least(UNDO retention, flashback archives retention, 120 hours).  Retention periods are usually pretty short, don't expect this to work well on any table with data more than 5 days old.

Comment: It was copied from the question @JohnDoyle; someone just edited that first :-).